# Extract ArrayList from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, iterator, sharedpreferences

I have an Activity in which the user gets to mark installed apps on his/her device as either Arcade, Educational, or Neither. In another activity, I want to isolate the Arcade selected apps only.

This is what I have:

```
    ArrayList<String> arcadeApps = null;

    SharedPreferences stored = getSharedPreferences("Sorted Apps", 0);

    Map<String, ?> mappedPreferences = stored.getAll();
    Iterator iterator = mappedPreferences.entrySet().iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry nextEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
        if(nextEntry.getValue().equals("Arcade")){
            arcadeApps.add((String) nextEntry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Is this doing what I want it to, in particular, is arcadeApps a list of all the apps that the user has qualified as "Arcade"? I'm sorry if it's a silly question I just don't know of a quick way to check this

Comment: It kind of depends how you are putting them in...This will return all preference keys whose value is "Arcade".

Comment: In the earlier activity I had `editor.putString(appName, "Category");` where appName is a string

Comment: Well then yes, this will return all the "appNames" of "Category".

Comment: Cool, thank you for confirming

Answer (score 0):

Did you store the ArrayList on the preferences? Theoretically you can not store on the preferences elements different from Boolean, Float, Int, Long, String and Set.
Practically there's a way to store ArrayLists on the preferences but this is not the best way to pass data between activities!

You should pass the data though the intent.

Suppose you have a map in which you stored information about each application.

```
HashMap<String, String> applicationsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
applicationsMap.put("MyApp1", "Arcade");
applicationsMap.put("MyApp2", "Educational");
```

Now pass this map to the second activity

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
activityIntent.putExtra("applicationsMap", applicationsMap);
// you can do it because HashMap<String, String> implements Serializable
```

Now, in the second activity (onCreate() method), recover the map

```
Intent activityIntent = getIntent();
HashMap<String,String> applicationsMap = (HashMap<String,String>)activityIntent.getExtras().getSerializable("applicationsMap");
```

Then you can read the map in the second activity and extract just those applications which have "Arcade" as value.